# Force use of a specific module version when two module versions exist

Tags: python, pkg-resources

```
import pkg_resources
pkg_resources.require("flask>=1.0.0")


import flask

print flask.__version__
```

OUTPUT:

```
$ python2.7 test_import_flask.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_import_flask.py", line 2, in <module>
    pkg_resources.require("flask>=1.0.0")
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 733, in require
    return needed
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 635, in resolve

pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (Flask 0.10.1 (/misc/toolchain-builds/a87ab33ee169dddc3c9eafd7586153de2017d6fb.x86_64/lib/py/Flask-0.10.1-py2.7.egg), Requirement.parse('flask>=1.0.0'))
```

But there are two versions of Flask

````
Flask-0.10.1-py2.7.egg -> /misc/toolchain-builds/a87ab33ee169dddc3c9eafd7586153de2017d6fb.x86_64/lib/py/Flask-0.10.1-py2.7.egg
Flask-1.1.2-py2.7.egg -> /misc/toolchain-builds/a87ab33ee169dddc3c9eafd7586153de2017d6fb.x86_64/lib/py/Flask-1.1.2-py2.7.egg```


how do i make sure the script uses Flask-1.1.2-py2.7.egg and not 0.10.1?
````

Comment: use virtualenv and install packages under it

Comment: yeah, @adrtam has the answer.  virtualenvs exist pretty much just to solve this problem.  With a virtualenv, you only install one version of any package, so there's no ambiguity and no reason to specify the version outside of your `requirements.txt` file.

Comment: @Steve I understand that but is there a way to specify the version of the module from the python script?

Comment: Not that I know of. - If anything, I'd think it might be handled by a command line parameter to the python executable